# FTP batch file download hangs at transfer

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, scheduled-tasks

I would apretiate any help with this.....
At title says, i have a batch file inside a scheduled task which generates an ftp file to download several thousand files from different folders daily, it does work for about half of the files but it randombly stops at the "125 Data conection already open; starting transfer", i can see that the file was partially downloaded (the file is 700kb in size and the temp file is 650 kb or so) but the download process got stuck for some reason.

-the bat file is called from a scheduled task
-about 15 folders with 1000 files each, and each file is from 20kb to 5mb in size
-download works from 3 to 5 folders and it gets stuck for some reason in mid transfer
-theres no error or message in the events registry
-using the native ftp client under windows 7 ultimate service pack 1
-same transfer using filezilla works fine but generates the mentioned error when trying to automatize

¿any help?  :(

heres part of the batch which handles the download:
%fechaftp% is my variable for date and name of folder to copy

```
REM HXOX---------------------------------------

echo lcd e:\HXOX\LAVAN\%fechaftp%\images>> temp.txt
echo cd  /HXOX/LAVAN/%fechaftp%/images>> temp.txt
echo mget *.jpg>> temp.txt

echo lcd e:\HXOX\LAVAN\%fechaftp%\record>> temp.txt
echo cd  /HXOX/LAVAN/%fechaftp%/record>> temp.txt
echo mget *.264>> temp.txt

echo lcd e:\HXOX\RECEP1\%fechaftp%>> temp.txt
echo cd  /HXOX/RECEP1>> temp.txt
echo mget *%fechaftp%*.mp4>> temp.txt

echo lcd e:\HXOX\RECEP2\%fechaftp%\images>> temp.txt
echo cd  /HXOX/RECEP2/%fechaftp%/images>> temp.txt
echo mget *.jpg>> temp.txt

echo lcd e:\HXOX\RECEP2\%fechaftp%\record>> temp.txt
echo cd  /HXOX/RECEP2/%fechaftp%/record>> temp.txt
echo mget *.264>> temp.txt

echo lcd e:\HXOX\RECEP3\%fechaftp%\images>> temp.txt
echo cd  /HXOX/RECEP3/%fechaftp%/images>> temp.txt
echo mget *.jpg>> temp.txt

echo lcd e:\HXOX\RECEP3\%fechaftp%\record>> temp.txt
echo cd  /HXOX/RECEP3/%fechaftp%/record>> temp.txt
echo mget *.264>> temp.txt

ftp -i -s:temp.txt
```

Comment: This isn't a code issue.  It is either an issue with the server or the network connection.  You should ask this question on a different Stack Exchange site as SO is for code problems.

Comment: The command-line `ftp` uses active mode. Are you able to download the same set of files in FileZilla using the active mode (FileZilla defaults to the passive mode) using a single connection (FileZilla defaults to multiple simultaneous connections)? Also FileZilla reconnects on failure, so make sure that the transfer in FileZilla is not actually failing too, but FileZilla was able to recover. Check the log file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed i am able to download the same files via filezilla without any error or connection issues, i tried something diferent and separated the downloads in 4 diferent batch files so i can transfer 4 files at a time, this has worked fine 4 times out of 5, the one time that didn't work all 4 transfers stoped again at the same message, that makes me think it's indeed a connection issue...